# Como ajustar a altura da uma UiView no Swift 3 de acordo com as subviews?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-3, xcode-8

Tenho uma UIView com subviews, e preciso que a UIView aumente ou diminua de acordo com o tamanho das subviews, a mesma ideia de um layout com wrap_content de altura. Alguém sabe como fazer isso no Swift 3? Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1):

Para ter este comportamento, você usara o `intrinsicContentSize` da `UIView`.

Para tal, basta adicionar `NSLayoutConstraint`s do topo até o rodapé de sua `UIView` "mãe".

Por exemplo, imagine que temos uma `UILabel` dentro de uma `UIView`. O retângulo em volta da `UILabel` representa esta `UIView`:

```
- - - - - - -
|  UILabel  |  
- - - - - - -
```

Ao usar o AutoLayout, no caso acima, como não temos `NSLayoutConstraint`s aplicadas à `UILabel`, o seu ponto de origem será `0,0` e a dimensão da `UIView` será o seu `CGRect` frame.

A partir do momento que adicionamos `NSLayoutConstraint`s, **por exemplo**, ao seu topo, esquerda, direita e rodapé **sem definir a altura da UILabel**, este comportamento muda: a `UIView` terá a dimensão da `UILabel`:

```
- - - - - - -
|     I     |
|--UILabel--|  
|     I     |
- - - - - - -
```